# C++ A Collection of Objects

Tags: c++, object, collections

i'm self learning C++ (using schaum's programming with c++ book), and i can't find anything in the book that explains how to create a collection of objects?
For example say you have a `class of books`, and a `class of stores`, and you want to create a collection of book objects in the store class, how would this be implemented?
I'm confused as with arrays you have to give a set size don't you? So what if you don't yet know the size needed? I'm assuming an array is not the best thing to use...
Also sorry if the book/store class example is a bad example. :)

Comment: Your book doesn't have a chapter on containers? (vectors, lists, sets, etc.)

Comment: well in those circumstances there are some classes considered standard (std::list for example) you could use for your evilish needs... or simply make the array ridicously huge :-)

Comment: You want to use a "container" like `std::vector`, `std::list`, etc.

Comment: Well it has a chapter on Vectors and Lists but it doesn't explain it as a collection of objects and it just confused me. I will give it a reread now I know they're collections :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be catching on quickly. No, arrays are generally not the best thing to use.

The standard library has a number of collection classes such as vector, deque, list, set, map, etc. From the sound of things, you might want a vector or a multimap. A vector is pretty much like an array, except that it resizes as needed when you insert objects. A map gives you the ability to look things up based on a field, such as looking a book up based on the title or author.

Comment: Ok thanks. I shall try to implement a Vector. Do you need to declare a size of the vector to begin with or can you create it empty? thanks.

Comment: @qwertyRocker: You can specify an initial size or create an empty vector.